# Import PHP's array of objects into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a php script which constructs an array of objects based on HTML input and then displays the results. What I am trying to do is to display the results page by page. Just like Google (or other search engines) display their results. When the user clicks next, the succeeding chunk of results is echoed back to the page.

Doing that with Javascript (a Javascript function is called as onClick event), I have to import the whole array prepared by the PHP script and index it accordingly. Here is part of the script so you know the kind of array

```
foreach($results as $id => $currentResult)
{
    $temp[$i]->id = $id;
    $page = get_page_by_id($id);
    $temp[$i]->url = $page['url'];
    $temp[$i]->title = $page['title'];
    $temp[$i]->score = $currentResult->score;
    ++$i;
}
$temp = qsort($temp);
```

So $temp is the array I am going to use in Javascript.
This can totally be eliminated by using PHP only but I'm trying to take the load off the server.

Comment: did you use some profiling tool like xdebug? you might be trying to optimize something that ain't workth it, a simple for shoudn't load a server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass value from PHP to js, use in your HTML template something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_array = <?php echo json_encode($my_array_to_path); ?>;
</script>
```

Then in your JS you can use next syntax:

```
my_array['some_key']; // or my_array.some_key
```

Great stuff, I think.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `json_encode` to send that array to javascript, and eval it there so that you get you data structure back.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using ajax 
$('#my_link_id').onClick(function()
{
//do ajax stuff, load from server
});

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

In PHP do this:

```
    $temp = qsort($temp);
    json_encode( $temp );
```

in HTML You can use jQuery to load the data back in:

```
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'some_page.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function( data ) {
          var returnObj = $.parseJSON( data );
          // and more code goes here
      }
    } );
```